# Cassandra cfstats wrong key estimate

Tags: cassandra, nodetool

I am trying to get the number of rows in a very large table, it has around 100k rows. I used:

> nodetool cfstats

And here is the result:

> Number of keys (estimate): 30

Why is the estimate so wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: not enough info here, need schema, version, what values you are changing. number of keys represents number of 'partitions' not cql rows.